# Update JSON for a PSCustomobject that must have the same NoteProperty names repeated

Tags: json, powershell

Been struggling with updating JSON for a PSCustomobject that has the same NoteProperty names repeated. This is to automate updating multiple Azure classic alert rules with a webhook.

This is what the Actions object within the rule JSON looks like when there's both a webhook and an email action. This example was created using the Azure portal UI

```
"actions":  [
                                   {
                                       "$type":  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
                                       "odata.type":  "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleWebhookAction",
                                       "serviceUri":  "http://www.webhooktest.com",
                                       "properties":  null
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "$type":  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
                                       "odata.type":  "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
                                       "sendToServiceOwners":  false,
                                       "customEmails":  [
                                                            "email2@domain.com",
                                                            "email1@domain.com" ]
                                    }
          ]
```

By default, only emails are enabled--see the example below. To add a webhook, I have to add another $type and odata.type, which are Note Properties

```
"actions":  [
                                   {
                                       "$type":  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
                                       "odata.type":  "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
                                       "sendtoserviceowners":  true,
                                       "customEmails":  [
                                                            "email2@domain.com",
                                                            "email1@domain.com" 
                                                        ]
                                   }
                               ]
```

---

```
    TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                MemberType   Definition                                                                                                                           
----                ----------   ----------                                                                                                                           
Equals              Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                       
GetHashCode         Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                    
GetType             Method       type GetType()                                                                                                                       
ToString            Method       string ToString()                                                                                                                    
$type               NoteProperty string $type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client
customEmails        NoteProperty Object[] customEmails=System.Object[]                                                                                                
odata.type          NoteProperty string odata.type=Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction                                                         
sendToServiceOwners NoteProperty bool sendToServiceOwners=False
```

The $type and odata.type note properties already exist for the email action, so adding another one (below) will fail, and if I use -Force, it will overwrite $type for the email action.

```
$action | Add-Member -NotePropertyName '$type' -NotePropertyValue "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client"
```

I'm stuck on how to add the webhook action without overwriting the email. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the linked question should help, Let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: It did, and thank you. I had searched before posting, but apparently not well enough. If I may add something--the linked post addresses adding two new objects, versus one, with multiple properties, which looks like this: $rule.properties.actions += [pscustomobject] @{'property1' = "Something";'property2' = "Something else"}